Is there a way to split a variable group value based on comma in YAML pipeline?
I have created a variable group with name as MyVariableGroup, which contains a variable like MyFileName.
MyFileName contains value like: File_1.csv,File_2.csv,File_3.csv
In my YAML pipeline I want to access this variable, split value based on comma, and then iterate through each element.
I have written this code:
steps:
- ${{ each filename in split(variables['MyFileName'], ',') }}:
  - script: |
      echo "Processing file: ${{ filename }}"
  displayName: 'Process File'

Why this code is not working?
I do not want to use Powershell/Bash command.
Please suggest a solution for this problem.
I have tried the code and pasted in the above comment section

Template expressions ${{ ... }} are processed at compile time, before the pipeline starts.
To reference a variable in a variable group, you can use macro syntax such as $(var) or a runtime expression such as $[variables.var]. These variables are process at runtime, i.e. their values are not available when the pipeline is compiled.
Workaround 1
If you really need to use a variable group but have a fixed number of files consider adding a distinct variable for each file as follows:

After referencing the variable group in the pipeline, add a compile-time variable which value contains a comma-separated list of variables from the variable group to include:
variables:
  - group: MyVariableGroup

  - name: MyFiles
    value: '$(file1),$(file2),$(file3)'

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - ${{ each file in split(variables.MyFiles, ',') }}:
    - script: |
        echo "Processing file: ${{ file }}"
      displayName: 'Processing file: ${{ file }}'

When the pipeline is compiled 3 script tasks are generated:
- script: |
    echo "Processing file: $(file1)"
  displayName: 'Processing file: $(file1)'

- script: |
    echo "Processing file: $(file2)"
  displayName: 'Processing file: $(file2)'

- script: |
    echo "Processing file: $(file3)"
  displayName: 'Processing file: $(file3)'

Finally, when running the pipeline values will be processed as expected:

Workaround 2
Use a compile-time variable instead of referencing a variable from a variable group:
variables:
  - name: MyFiles
    value: 'File_1.csv,File_2.csv,File_3.csv'

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - ${{ each file in split(variables.MyFiles, ',') }}:
    - script: |
        echo "Processing file: ${{ file }}"
      displayName: 'Processing file: ${{ file }}'

Running the pipeline:


Thank you very much for your quick response.
For my use case, the number of files will change.
So, is there any other approach which can handle n number of files?
Any leads will be highly appreciated.
TIA

@Swarnava added another answer.


For my use case, the number of files will change. So, is there any other approach which can handle n number of files?

Assuming a dynamic comma-separated list of of files such as file1,file2,...,fileN and considering that template expressions ${{ ... }} are processed at compile time (before the pipeline starts) the only option is to trigger another build to process the files.
Source pipeline that queues a new build using az pipelines run:
name: source-pipeline_$(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)

variables:
  - group: MyVariableGroup # contains variable 'MyFileName'

steps:
  - checkout: none

  - script: >-
      az pipelines run
      --name 'triggered'
      --org $(System.CollectionUri)
      --project $(System.TeamProject)
      --branch $(Build.SourceBranch)
      --parameters "files=$(MyFileName)"
    displayName: 'Queue pipeline'
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

Notes:

--parametersis a space separated pairs for the parameters you would like to set, for example param1=value1 param2=value2
--branch $(Build.SourceBranch) queues the pipeline using the same branch as the source pipeline

Pipeline triggered:
name: triggered-pipeline_$(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)

parameters:
  - name: files
    displayName: 'A comma-separated list of files'
    type: string
    default: 'f1,f2,f3'

jobs:
  # use a different job for each file in order to process them in parallel
  - ${{ each file in split(parameters.files, ',') }}:
    - job: ${{ replace(file, '.csv', '') }}
      displayName: 'Processing file: ${{ file }}'
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - script: |
            echo "Processing file: ${{ file }}"
          displayName: 'Processing file: ${{ file }}'

Don't forget to set the appropriate permissions to the pipeline being triggered:

